# pydantic build list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a body like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "product": "WMQ"
    },
    {
      "name": "James",
      "product": "WPB"
    }
  ]
}
```

And main.py as such:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class Items(TypedDict):
    name: str 
    product: str 

class Predictions(BaseModel):
    data: list[Items]
```

I would like to have a list of dicts, but not named , such that I could pass a body like that:

```
 [
    {
      "name": "Alex",
      "product": "WMQ"
    },
    {
      "name": "James",
      "product": "WPB"
    }
  ]
```

Is it possible to have this in pydantic ? Can I do this by constructing a single class ?